# How to get element type in xpath?

Tags: xpath, xquery

My xml is:

```
<record>
  <field name="f1"/>
  <id name="f2"/>
  <id name="f3"/>
  <field name="f4"/>
  <info/>
</record>
```

I want to loop through it in xquery like this:

```
for $i in $records/record/field | $records/record/id
return
   if ( .... $i is id .... ) then .... do something .... else ... do something else ...
```

Is this possible? How can distinguish when `$i` is id and when it is field?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Another neat XQuery solution is to use typeswitch:

```
for $i in $records/record/field | $records/record/id
return
  typeswitch($i)
  case element(id) return ...
  case element(field) return ...
  default return ...
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of those attempts with name() or local-name() I would use self::id e.g.

```
if ($i[self::id]) then ... else ...
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a function library or create your own user defined function.  Something like this:

```
for $i in $records/record/field | $records/record/id
return
   if (name($i)="id") then .... do something .... else ... do something else ...
```

http://www.xqueryfunctions.com/xq/fn_name.html

Comment: I've never used XQuery, but it looks to me like you might mean `name($i)` rather than `name($1)`, unless XQuery is even weirder than it looks to me!

Answer (score 0):

Check out the `local-name` XQuery function - see the [MSDN docs here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190650.aspx).

Given a node or a node set, it should give you the node's name - the name of the tag. I guess that's what you're looking for, right??

E.g. if you do this:

```
DECLARE @input XML = '<record>
  <field name="f1"/>
  <id name="f2"/>
  <id name="f3"/>
  <field name="f4"/>
  <info/>
</record>'

SELECT 
    inp.nod.query('local-name(.)')
FROM 
    @input.nodes('//*') AS inp(nod)
```

You get an output like this:

```
record
field
id
id
field
info
```

Answer (score 0):

How about something simpler and more XQuery-like

```
for $i in $records/record/field return do something with field,
for $i in $records/record/id return do something with id
```

In this case, the values returned by the first for will be merged with the values from the 2nd for.

Comment: The result will be field-field-id-id but I wanted field-id-id-field.

Answer (score 0):

Use typeswitch:

```
let $record :=
<record>
  <field name="f1"/>
  <id name="f2"/>
  <id name="f3"/>
  <field name="f4"/>
  <info/>
</record>

for $e in $record/*
return
  typeswitch ($e) 
    case element(id) return concat("id",$e/@name)
    case element (field) return concat("field",$e/@name)
    default return "other"
```